# SharePoint 2007 Navigation Editing and Sorting-no info in the info pane

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a user that cannot see the info in the Navigation Editing and Sorting section (site actions->site settings->navigation).  She has full control of the website via group permissions.  The strange thing is that her backup (also part of the same group permissions) can see the sites/links information.

I have checked her permissions, tried removing and re-adding her from the group, had her flush her cache, but am not sure what to check now.  Maybe her AD account?  Has anyone else had this problem?